# Uniform distribution on the simplex. - Cover & Thomas

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, information-theory

I'm trying to formulate the solution for the following problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq0PO.png]

I was thinking in finding the equivalent distribution on $X_i$ based on $Y_i$, but I think I'm cheating. I think that the autor wants that we find the answer by setting a set of types, and then calcullating the Kullback-leibler distance between the type $P_{X_i}(x)$ and the uniform distribution.

Thanks!

Comment: Your finding the distribution of each $X_i$, plus induction, seems a reasonable way to go

Comment: You can draw pictures in the case $n=2:$ they will suggest the correct answers in higher dimensions.  You should be able to demonstrate that (b) and (c) are equivalent.

Comment: Please add `self-study` to the tags.